# EM algorithm for MLE from a bivariate normal sample with missing data: Stuck on M-step

Tags: maximum-likelihood, missing-data, expectation-maximization, multivariate-normal-distribution, bivariate

I'm trying to understand applying the EM algorithm to compute the MLE in a missing data problem.

Specifically, suppose $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)$ is a random sample from the bivariate normal distribution with mean $(0,0)$ and unknown covariance matrix
$$
\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_x^2&\rho\sigma_x\sigma_y\\
\rho\sigma_x\sigma_y&\sigma_y^2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I want to find the MLE of $\Sigma$ given that the first $\nu< n$ of the $y$-coordinates are missing.

For the E-step of the EM algorithm, I need to compute

$$
Q_i(\Sigma,\tilde\Sigma):=
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{E}_{y\sim f(y\mid x_i,\tilde\Sigma)}[\log f(x_i,y\mid\Sigma)]&
\text{if }1\leq i\leq \nu,\\
\log f(x_i,y_i\mid\Sigma)&\text{if }\nu< i\leq n,
\end{cases}
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
-\log f(x,y\mid\Sigma)
= \log2\pi &+ \frac12\log\sigma_x^2 + \frac12\log\sigma_y^2
+ \frac12\log(1-\rho^2)\\
&+ \frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}
\left\{\frac{x^2}{\sigma_x^2}
- \frac{2\rho xy}{\sigma_x\sigma_y}
+ \frac{y^2}{\sigma_y^2}\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$
\tilde\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
\tilde\sigma_x^2&\tilde\rho\tilde\sigma_x\tilde\sigma_y\\
\tilde\rho\tilde\sigma_x\tilde\sigma_y&\tilde\sigma_y^2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Since
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}_{y\sim f(y\mid x_i,\tilde\Sigma)} [y] &= \frac{\tilde\rho \tilde\sigma_yx_i}{\tilde\sigma_x},\\
\mathbb{E}_{y\sim f(y\mid x_i,\tilde\Sigma)}[y^2] &=\tilde\sigma_y^2(1-\tilde\rho^2) + \frac{\tilde\rho^2 \tilde\sigma^2_yx_i^2}{\tilde\sigma_x^2},
\end{aligned}
$$

I get that

$$
\begin{aligned}
-Q_i(\Sigma,\tilde\Sigma) =
\log2\pi &+ \frac12\log\sigma_x^2 + \frac12\log\sigma_y^2
+ \frac12\log(1-\rho^2)\\
&+ \frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}
\left\{\frac{x_i^2}{\sigma_x^2}
- \frac{2\rho\tilde\rho\tilde\sigma_y^2 x_i^2}{\sigma_x\tilde\sigma_x\sigma_y}
+ \frac{\tilde\sigma_x^2\tilde\sigma_y^2(1-\tilde\rho^2)+ \tilde\rho^2 \tilde\sigma^2_yx_i^2}{\tilde\sigma_x^2\sigma_y^2}
\right\}.
\end{aligned}
$$

for $1\leq i\leq \nu$.

Now, for the M-step, I need to compute
$$
\operatorname*{argmax}_{\Sigma} \sum_{i=1}^n Q_i(\Sigma,\tilde\Sigma).
$$

And here I'm stuck. Is there a nice form for the optimal $\Sigma$?

Comment: Added missing 0.5*log(1-rho^2) term. Thanks!

Comment: Added the $-$ sign as suggested. Thanks again, Xi'an.

Comment: Fixed that, too. Also and a commentary on your hint. I included it as an answer (even though your answer is the answer, @xian) since it was too long to fit in a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** When considering
\begin{aligned}
\log f(x_i,y_i\mid\Sigma)
= -\log2\pi &- \frac12\log\sigma_x^2 - \frac12\log\sigma_y^2
- \frac12\log(1-\rho^2)\\
&+ \frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}
\left\{\frac{x_i^2}{\sigma_x^2}
- \frac{2\rho x_iy_i}{\sigma_x\sigma_y}
+ \frac{y^2}{\sigma_y^2}\right\}
\end{aligned}
and
\begin{aligned}
Q_i(\Sigma,\tilde\Sigma) =
&-\log2\pi- \frac12\log\sigma_x^2 - \frac12\log\sigma_y^2
- \frac12\log(1-\rho^2)\\
&+ \frac{1/2}{(1-\rho^2)}
\left\{\frac{x_i^2}{\sigma_x^2}
- \frac{2\rho x_i\tilde\rho\tilde\sigma_y x_i}{\sigma_x\tilde\sigma_x\sigma_y}
+ \frac{\tilde\sigma_y^2(1-\tilde\rho^2)+\tilde\rho^2\tilde\sigma_y^2 x_i^2/\tilde\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_y^2}
\right\}
\end{aligned}
both expressions are essentially of identical shapes as functions of $\Sigma$. This means that the objective function to optimize writes as
\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^\nu\, &\log f(x_i,\mathbb E_{y\sim f(y\mid x_i,\tilde\Sigma)}[y_i]\mid\Sigma)+\\
\sum_{i=1}^\nu\, &\left\{\log f(0,\tilde\sigma_y(1-\tilde\rho^2)^{1/2})\mid\Sigma)+\log2\pi + \frac12\log[\sigma_x^2 \sigma_y^2(1-\rho^2)]\right\}+\\\sum_{i\nu+=1}^n\, &\log f(x_i,\tilde y_i\mid\Sigma)\end{align}
i.e. as a [regular Normal log-likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/391700/7224) for a modified Normal sample $\mathbf Z$ (depending on the current $\tilde\Sigma$)
$$
-\frac n2 \log|\Sigma|-\frac12\text{trace}(\mathbf Z \Sigma^{-1})
$$
The estimator of $\Sigma$ can thus be derived [as in the Normal case](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/351550/7224).

Answer (score 1):

To flesh out @xian's answer (and to make sure I understand it!):

For $1\leq i\leq \nu$, let
$$
\begin{aligned}
\tilde y_i
& = \mathbb{E}_{y\sim f(y\mid x_i,\tilde\Sigma)}[y],\\
\tilde z_i^2
& = \operatorname{Var}_{y\sim f(y\mid x_i,\tilde\Sigma)}[y].
\end{aligned}
$$

We have:
$$
\tilde z_i^2 = \mathbb{E}_{y\sim f(y\mid x_i,\tilde\Sigma)}[y^2]
- \tilde y_i^2
$$

If $1\leq i\leq \nu$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
Q_i(\Sigma,\tilde\Sigma)
&= \mathbb{E}_{y\sim f(y\mid x_i,\tilde\Sigma)}[\log f(x_i,y\mid\Sigma)]\\
&= \mathbb{E}_{y\sim f(y\mid x_i,\tilde\Sigma)}\left[-\log2\pi - \frac12\log\Sigma
- \frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}
\left\{\frac{x_i^2}{\sigma_x^2}
- \frac{2\rho x_iy}{\sigma_x\sigma_y}
+ \frac{y^2}{\sigma_y^2}\right\}\right]\\
&= -\log2\pi - \frac12\log\Sigma
- \frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}
\left\{\frac{x_i^2}{\sigma_x^2}
- \frac{2\rho x_i\tilde y_i}{\sigma_x\sigma_y}
+ \frac{\mathbb{E}_{y\sim f(y\mid x_i,\tilde\Sigma)}[y^2]}{\sigma_y^2}\right\}\\
&= -\log2\pi - \frac12\log\Sigma
- \frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}
\left\{\frac{x_i^2}{\sigma_x^2}
- \frac{2\rho x_i\tilde y_i}{\sigma_x\sigma_y}
+ \frac{\tilde y_i^2}{\sigma_y^2}\right\}
- \frac{\tilde z_i^2}{2\sigma_y^2(1-\rho^2)}\\
&= \log f(x_i,\tilde y_i\mid\Sigma)
- \frac{\tilde z_i^2}{2\sigma_y^2(1-\rho^2)}.
\end{aligned}
$$

The term $\log f(x_i,\tilde y_i\mid\Sigma)$ is intuitively appealing; we've imputed the unknown $y$-values with their conditional expectations.

Let's consider the correction term:

$$
- \frac{\tilde z_i}{2\sigma_y^2(1-\rho^2)}
= \log f(0,\tilde z_i\mid\Sigma) + \frac12\log 2\pi + \frac12\log\det\Sigma.
$$

Thus, if $1\leq i\leq \nu$,
$$
Q_i(\Sigma,\tilde\Sigma) 
= \log f(x_i,\tilde y_i\mid\Sigma)
+ \log f(0,\tilde z_i\mid\Sigma) + \frac12\log 2\pi + \frac12\log\det\Sigma.
$$

The M-step involves maximizing the function
$$
\begin{aligned}
Q(\Sigma,\tilde\Sigma) &:= \sum_{i=1}^n Q_i(\Sigma,\tilde\Sigma)
\end{aligned}
$$

Being essentially sum of Gaussian log-likelihoods and "simple" correction terms, we can maximize $Q(\Sigma,\tilde\Sigma)$ using standard techniques. Unless I messed something up (likely), the resulting maximizer is

$$
\Sigma = \frac1n\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2&
\sum_{i=1}^\nu x_i \tilde y_i
+ \sum_{i=\nu+1}^n x_i y_i\\
\sum_{i=1}^\nu x_i \tilde y_i
+ \sum_{i=\nu+1}^n x_i y_i&
\sum_{i=1}^\nu (\tilde y_i^2 + \tilde{z}_i^2)
+ \sum_{i=\nu+1}^n y_i^2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: This sounds correct.